# How to Create a WCF Rest Endpoint for Uploading Large Files to ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax, wcf

Can WCF be used to create an endpoint for uploading large files to a website via an ASP.NET MVC controller method, with a jQuery progress bar in the browser being updated with Ajax or Json?

How would it be done?  Are code samples available?

Answer (score 2):

There's an MSDN article on large files and WCF. [Large Data and Streaming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733742.aspx)
In the web.config of the WCF service you have to increase the maxRequestLength (described on [maxRequestLength](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.httpruntimesection.maxrequestlength.aspx)

The view should look like this

```
 <%using(Html.BeginForm("ActionName",  
                        "ControllerName",  
                        FormMethod.Post,  
                        new {enctype = "multipart/form-data"})) {%> ...
```

The controller should look like the following

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]  
    public ActionResult ActionName(HttpPostedFileBase file)  
    {
         ....
```